# How to display divs correctly

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

https://jsfiddle.net/qz8hL574/1/

```
for (var key in table) {
    if (table.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        $('<div class="element"></div>').appendTo('#list');
        document.getElementsByClassName("element")[key].innerHTML = table[key].symbol;
    }
}
```

That's how a div is filled.

My code is there. When I run it locally I get this http://prntscr.com/knwyh0
What means that the one and only element to be displayed is the last one.
All the divs are there and are correctly filled with values from the object, but if I give a z-index equal to 100 to a random one it does not go on top and is not displayed. I wish, I could see them in one column aligned center-horizontally. Any ideas how can I fix it?

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't run

Comment: Just change your #list elements position from absolute to relative to show them inline.

Comment: Adding a `z-index` to an element works just fine, so you need to provide a better sample, that reproduce the issue you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know exactly what you mean.. But maybe something like this?

```
#list {
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}


#list .element {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

position absolute as you were using puts the divs on an absolut position relative it its parent.. This means all will be in the same location, overlaping...

Comment: If you don't know what the OP mean, ask first and then post an answer. As you can't comment, be patient and start answering questions that doesn't need clarifications until you can.